# How to display WFS Layer from Geoserver using OpenLayers 

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wfs

I'm new in Geoserver and OpenLayers Could you tell me how to display GML Layer from Geoserver using OpenLayers ??
I Would like to show the labels for each Feature

Answer (score 3):

Tutorials...

http://workshops.opengeo.org/stack-intro/openlayers.html

http://workshops.opengeo.org/stack-intro/geoserver.html

Comment: I've follow the tutorial above.nothing error, but nothing shown on OpenLayers Map

Comment: var wfslayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS", {
                    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
                    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                        url:  "http://localhost:1234/geoserver/wfs",
                        featureType: "mobilegis:perkantoran",
                        featureNS: "http://postgis.org",
                        srsName: "EPSG:32752",
                        version: "1.1.0"
                    })
                });

                map.addLayer(wfslayer);

Comment: neither of these tutorials are available any longer.